# Serial connection is opening all ports?

Tags: c++, mfc, serial-port

I'm creating UART Interface with MFC, the interface include open connection, send message and receive message.
I thought I had opened the port fine, after checking, my D9 connector is sitting over COM5, which opened successfully.
The issue is that even changing the connection from COM5 to the unreasonable COM535, I still didn't received any errors

I've tried several COM port, some reasonable and some not.

This is how I initialize the connection to the bad COM:

```
Serial::Serial(CString &commPortName, int bitRate)
{
    commHandle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM535", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0,NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED , NULL);

    if(commHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        throw("ERROR: Could not open com port");
    }
    else 
    {
        // set timeouts
        COMMTIMEOUTS cto = { MAXDWORD, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        DCB dcb;
        if(!SetCommTimeouts(commHandle,&cto))
        {
            Serial::~Serial();
            throw("ERROR: Could not set com port time-outs");
        }

        // set DCB
        memset(&dcb,0,sizeof(dcb));
        dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);
        dcb.BaudRate = bitRate;
        dcb.fBinary = 1;
        dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
        dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;

        dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
        dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
        dcb.ByteSize = 8;

        if(!SetCommState(commHandle,&dcb))
        {
            Serial::~Serial();
            throw("ERROR: Could not set com port parameters");
        }
    }
}
```

When I connect to COM5 it's all good, but I expect to have an issue connecting to COM535 which I dont, and that's not how it should be.

Comment: Since you are using MFC, I'm assuming you are using Windows Operating System.  This is not a C++ issue and more of an issue with Windows API.  You'll have to look up the function and find out what errors are generated when an invalid COM number is supplied.

Comment: Already have checked it, I set Serial data member at the constructor of CUARTDlg, when I use one of the method of the Serial class, the connection is established, the complier will return comHandle=0xfffffffff for bad attempt in connecting, which it does not

Answer (score 0):

The "issue" was my own workplace issue, restarted my PC and I started to get the errors for bad COM port